# Микроразметка сайта

Tags: html

Никак не могу понять что значит микроразметка сайта, в двух словах кто нибудь может объяснить?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/company/promopult/blog/486764/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Никак не могу понять что значит микроразметка сайта, в двух словах кто
>   нибудь может объяснить?

*В двух словах так:*

**Schema.org** — семантическая разметка страниц сайта, которая структурирует данные. Это единый и общепризнанный стандарт, распознаваемый наиболее популярными поисковыми системами.

Микро разметка **Open Graph** по большей части необходима для социальных сетей и мессенджеров, чтобы ссылки на сайт отображались более красиво и информативно.

Comment: будет отображаться красиво ?

Comment: что красивого то от og.title og.image ?

Comment: @Sevastopol' Надо попробовать )

Comment: nonsense, in my opinion, it is

Comment: самое крутое что будет - это отображаться в поисковике ...

Answer (score 2):

Микроразметка нужна для большего понимания сайтами поисковиками (Google, Yandex, Yahoo и другие) и для большего распознавания контента на вашем сайте, странице. Больше можно [тут](https://netpeak.net/ru/blog/mikrorazmetka-chto-nuzhno-znat-seo-spetsialistu-o-slovaryakh-i-sintaksise/) почитать.